# C++ beginner problem: re-using threads at every iteration of a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, k-means

Hi everyone.

I'm trying to learn the basics of modern C++ multithreading. I'm doing so by implementing a multithreaded version of the kmeans clustering algorithm, but I'm struggling quite a bit on managing threads inside a for loop.

This is my setting: I have a NxD matrix of data points:

```cpp
template <typename T, const size_t N, const size_t D>
mat<T, N, D> data
```

where

```cpp
mat<T, N, D> = std::array<vec<T, D>, N>
vec<T, D> = std::array<T, D>
```

are my typedefs.

From this matrix I sample a small subset of M points, obtaining a MxD matrix:

```cpp
template <typename T, const size_t M, const size_t D>
mat<T, M, D> clusters
```

At each iteration (where the total number is set by the user) the algorithm calculates the closest cluster with respect to every point in the data set, and then proceeds by updating the clusters to the barycenter of every set of nodes assigned at each one of them ---> [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

This is my sequential version:

```cpp
template <typename T, const size_t N, const size_t M, const size_t D>
mat<T, M, D> kmeans(const mat<T, N, D>& data, mat<T, M, D>& centroids, const size_t niter) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < niter; ++i) {
        vec<size_t, N> assignment = calc_assignment<T, N, M, D>(data, centroids);
        centroids = update_centroids<T, N, M, D>(data, assignment);
    }
    return centroids;
}

template <typename T, const size_t N, const size_t M, const size_t D>
vec<size_t, N> calc_assignment(const mat<T, N, D>& data, const mat<T, M, D>& centroids) {
    vec<size_t, N> assignment;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        assignment[i] = get_closest_centroid<T, M, D>(data[i], centroids);
    return assignment;
}

template <typename T, const size_t N, const size_t M, const size_t D>
mat<T, M, D> update_centroids(const mat<T, N, D>& data, const vec<size_t, N>& assignment) {
    mat<T, M, D> new_centroids {};
    vec<size_t, M> counts {};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        new_centroids[assignment[i]] = new_centroids[assignment[i]] + data[i];
        counts[assignment[i]] += 1;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        new_centroids[i] = new_centroids[i] / counts[i];
    return new_centroids;
}

template<typename T, const size_t M, const size_t D>
size_t get_closest_centroid(const vec<T, D>& point, const mat<T, M, D>& centroids) {
    vec<double, M> distances;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; ++i)
        distances[i] = calc_distance<T, D>(point, centroids[i]);
    auto min_dist = std::min_element(distances.begin(), distances.end());
    return std::distance(distances.begin(), min_dist);
}

template<typename T, const size_t D>
double calc_distance(const vec<T, D>& p, const vec<T, D>& q) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < D; ++i)
        sum += std::pow((p[i] - q[i]), 2);
    return sum;
}
```

which runs quite fast, thanks to the optimizations (and vectorization) operated by the compiler. The `kmeans` method runs in ~0.6s on my laptop (with tons of firefox tabs and other stuff running...) for a data set of 100k 2D-points.

Going to the multithreading world: I hoped that future and promises could be sufficient for my purpose, hence I modified my previous code in order to split the load between a previously-fixed number of threads:

```cpp
template <typename T, const size_t N, const size_t M, const size_t D>
    std::vector<size_t> calc_subset_assignment(const mat<T, N, D>& data, const mat<T, M, D>& centroids, 
                                               const size_t start, const size_t end) {
        std::vector<size_t> partial_assignment;
        partial_assignment.reserve(end - start);
        for (size_t i = start; i < end; ++i)
            partial_assignment.emplace_back(kmeans::calc::get_closest_centroid<T, M, D>(data[i], centroids));
        return partial_assignment;
    }

    template <typename T, const size_t N, const size_t M, const size_t D>
    std::vector<size_t> calc_assignment_mt(const mat<T, N, D>& data, const mat<T, M, D>& centroids, const size_t nthreads) {
        std::vector<size_t> assignment;
        assignment.reserve(N);
        std::vector<std::future<std::vector<size_t>>> futures;
        futures.reserve(nthreads);
        const size_t step = (N + nthreads - 1) / nthreads;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += step) {
            size_t real_step = (i + step > N) ? N - i : step;
            futures.emplace_back(std::async(calc_subset_assignment<T, N, M, D>, data, centroids, i, i+real_step));
        }
        for (auto& f : futures) {
            std::vector<size_t> partial_assignment = f.get();
            assignment.insert(assignment.end(), 
                              std::make_move_iterator(partial_assignment.begin()), 
                              std::make_move_iterator(partial_assignment.end()));
        }
        return assignment;
    }
```

Now, since the `calc_assignment_mt` runs inside a for loop of a (potentially large) number of iterations, I thought that maybe creating and destroying threads at each iteration could slow down the whole thing and, in fact, that's what happened: the `kmeans` method takes almost 2x the time it takes in the sequential form, under the same setting.

Do you have any advice on how to attack this kind of problem? Thanks for reading the whole lot of it, and for your attention.

Comment: You can use a profiler to see where the bottlenecks are. One place of contention is memory allocation. Reuse the `partial_assignment` vector (in `calc_subset_assignment`) instead of destroying and recreating it every iteration. Overall minor tweak: don't use `pow` to square a number.

Comment: not much point using more threads than you have CPU cores, for some workloads double the number of threads may work better, more than that and you end up paying too much for context switches and thread creation